# How do I get the list of columns from a DataFrameGroupBy object?

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm working on a project where it's often easier to work on pandas `DataFrameGroupBy` objects instead of `DataFrame` objects. But in one instance I need to know the columns present in the `DataFrameGroupBy`.

Does the `DataFrameGroupBy` api offer a nice way to access this?

The best I'm aware of is, given a `dfg: DataFrameGroupBy`,

```
dfg.get_group(next(iter(dfg.groups.keys()))).columns
```

which returns the columns index for the first group.

I'm wondering if there's a better way. chatgpt hallucinated big time when i asked about this.

Comment: Try `group.obj.columns` it is a private attribute though

Comment: whoaaa. any downsides to this? is it a computed @property? what should i know. (being private doesn't seem bad to me, unless you mean it might go away in a future release)

Comment: wait - what is `group`? if it's a group returned by `get_groups`, isn't that just a DataFrame?

Comment: Group is the groupby object -> `dfg.obj.columns`

Comment: If you look at the source code for `get_group`, you should have a better insight into the `obj` attribute

Comment: However, take care if you delayed the use of the `DataFrameGroupBy`. The `obj` attribute is a reference to the underlying dataframe. If you modify it inplace, you can have unexpected behavior (like `df.drop(..., inplace=True`)

Comment: I personally find it the easiest to simply select a small subset of the `DataFrameGroupBy` and collects its columns, e.g. via the head method -- `dfg.head(1).columns`